# How to increase the number of options with single choice questions created with ```num_to_schoice```

Tags: r, r-exams

I know that the function `num_to_schoice` creates a question list of five elements, but is there some simple workaround to create, say, a question list of eight or ten elements and only one correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently the five alternatives are hard-coded. The main reason is that the feature is most appealing for written exams that can be automatically scanned, i.e., `exams2nops()`. And this can have at most five answer alternatives, hence `num_to_schoice()` is compatible with that.

Comment: I understand, but I think it can be useful to create more options with Moodles. I have written a .Rnw file: 
`k=9; 

sol=0.3;

sc=num_to_schoice(sol, digits=2, range=c(0.01, 0.99), delta=0.01, method='delta');


  
 while (length(unique(sc$questions))<k) {


sc0= num_to_schoice(0.3, digits=2, range=c(0.01, 0.99), delta=0.01, method='delta');



sc$questions= unique(c(paste0("$",sol,"$"), 
           sc$questions[sc$solutions==F], sc0$questions[sc0$solutions==F]));

sc$solutions = c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, length(sc$questions)-1))

}

`  and `\exshuffle{\Sexpr{k}}` Is this ok?

Comment: Before looking at this in detail: Why do you want to do this in Moodle via single-choice exercises? Why not simple use a numeric exercise? I use the single-choice route only for written exams that need to be scanned automatically. For that single-choice is much easier than worrying about optical character recognition. But in Moodle or other learning management systems reading numbers is no problem.

Comment: You are right. In Moodle it's better to use numeric exercises. And for written exams with scanning, it is not possible to increase the number of options.